# How to play an audio to notify when new record is inserted in collection(cursor.observeChanges) in Meteor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I have a meteor app where I was trying to notify on client side when new record is entered in to the collection.For this I tried using cursor.observeChanges and able to give a notification message on client side..But additional to this I need play small audio or an alert so that we can easily identify it .I tried but it was not working

```
var cursor = customerDetails.find();
    cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, object) {
   Notification.error('NEW Record');
   var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
    audio.addEventListener('cursor.observeChanges', function() {
        console.log("Inside Audio");
    audio.play();
    });
     }
    });
```

I saved the audio file in public folder.Can someone help how can i play this

Comment: Do you get any errors? Does the "Inside Audio" work?

Comment: No...Even am not getting log Inside Audio

Comment: Yes I have in my collection.js file and i no errors there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding an event listener every time the record is added, but the listener does not get triggered. Instead, you should just run `audio.play()` whenever the record is added.

```
var audio = new Audio('audio.mp3');
var cursor = customerDetails.find();
cursor.observeChanges({
    added: function(id, object) {
        Notification.error('NEW Record');
        console.log("Record added")
        audio.play();
    }
});
```